# Java Calculations

Tags: java

Why does:

```
System.out.println((3 + 7 + 10) * (1000 - 8) / (992 - 17))
```

print `3` and not `20`?

```
System.out.println (2.0 + 1.0/2 + 1.0/6 + 1.0/24 + 1.0/120)
```

print `2.7166666666666663` and not `2.716666667`?

```
System.out.println (2147483647 + 1)
```

print `-2147483648` and not `2147483648`?

Comment: The first one should print `3`...what are you expecting? Check the Java tutorial about operator precedence: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: @OpMt I don't understand your edit.

Comment: @OpMt You realize that the parentheses you added in your last edit are incorrect, right? With the added parentheses, the value of the first statement is 20, not 3. Without the added parentheses the value is 3, not 20. The parentheses influence the order in which operations are performed and hence the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> System.out.println((3 + 7 + 10) * (1000 - 8) / 992 - 17) print 3 and not 20?

[Order of operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations). Evaluate the parenthesis first to get (20) * (992) / 992 - 17. Then, multiplication and division from left to right to get 20 - 17. Finally, subtraction to get 3.

> System.out.println (2.0 + 1.0/2 + 1.0/6 + 1.0/24 + 1.0/120) print 2.7166666666666663 and not 2.716666667?

Floating point arithmetic. There are [lots of questions here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=floating%20point%20math) about floating point math, and a quick Google search will probably turn up more than you could ever need. The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point_arithmetic) might be a good start, though.

> System.out.println (2147483647 + 1) print -2147483648 and not 2147483648?

Overflow. The maximum value of an integer in Java is 2^31 - 1 or 2,147,483,647. When you add one to that value, it wraps around to the value you see. It has to do with the binary representation of the value using [2s compliment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2s_compliment).

Comment: There are two curious and helpful links related with this issues:

https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/the_need_for_bigdecimal

http://epramono.blogspot.com.es/2005/01/double-vs-bigdecimal.html

Answer (score 4):

```
System.out.println((3 + 7 + 10) * (1000 - 8) / 992 - 17)
```

This prints 3 and not 20 because of... basic math...

- 3 + 7 + 10 = 20
- 1000 - 8 = 992
- 20 * 992 / 992 - 17 = 20 - 17
- 20 - 17 = 3

---

```
System.out.println (2.0 + 1.0/2 + 1.0/6 + 1.0/24 + 1.0/120)
```

That's a floating-point precision error.

---

```
System.out.println (2147483647 + 1)
```

Integer overflow.

Comment: So for Integer overflow, why does it turn into a negative?

Comment: @OpMt: Because `2147483647` is `0b01111111111111111111111111111111` and it overflows into `0b10000000000000000000000000000000`, which is `-2147483648` as a signed, two's complement, 32-bit integer, which is what `int` is.

Comment: @Nambari That's incorrect. It has to do with the binary representation and [2s compliment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2s_compliment). The behavior is well-defined and well-understood.

Answer (score 1):

1. `(3 + 7 + 10) * (1000 - 8) / 992 - 17` is `20 * 992 / 992 - 17`, which boils down to `20 - 17` and is therefore `3`, not `20`.
2. Floating-point arithmetic is inherently inaccurate.
3. Signed overflow is well-defined behavior in Java. `2147483647` is `0x7fffffff` in Java; `0x7fffffff + 1` is `0x80000000`, or, in other words, `-2147483648`.

Answer (score 0):

could not understand what you tried to convey by the first print statement, there is nothing wrong in the output. in the 3rd case, int is of 32 bits and the number is out of range. put an l after the big number(to treat is as long) to get the right output.

Answer (score 0):

regarding #3:

System.out.println (2147483647 + 1) will print out 2147483648 if you use a long. Each variable type has a maximum capacity.